# Avoid chaning css and js everytime in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using plenty of CSS and JavaScript in my CodeIgniter application.

Here is my sample controller.

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('site/title');
    $this->load->view('site/menu');
    $this->load->view('site/asset');
    $this->load->view('site/css');
    $this->load->view('site/js');
    $this->load->view('site/content');
}
```

Though I load the CSS files and JavaScript files in the view itself like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What I want is if I change the CSS folder location to some other i.e., `(asset/css)` I need to change the path in all the functions. How can I avoid this and make it simple?

Comment: You can do $config['css'] = yourcss.css and load it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by it by creating a common loader, which loads **css, js and menu** by default and then loading the **main content** dynamically according to the need.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class site extends CI_Controller 
{
//public loader here
public function loader($common)
{
  $this->load->view($common);
  $this->load->view('site/asset'); //which contains the css, js and menu folder
}
//index page here
public function index()
    {
    $this->loader('index');
    }
//about page here
public function about()
    {
    $this->loader('about');
    }
//blog page here
public function blog()
    {
    $this->loader('blog');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your assets in an array then do a `foreach` loop:

```
<?php

    $assets = array ( 'all.css', 'theme.css', ... );

    foreach($assets as $asset) {
        echo "<link href=\"<?php echo base_url()?>css/" . $asset . "\" rel=\"stylesheet\">" . "\n";
    }

?>
```

output:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a library to manage your assets in `app/libraries` like

#### Assets.php

```
class Assets{

   /** url to assets dir */
   protected $urlToAssets

    /** @var array */
    protected $cssFiles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->urlToAssets = base_url('assets/');
        $this->cssFiles = array();
    }

    function addCss($name)
    {
        $this->cssFiles[] = $name
    }

    function printCssFiles()
    {
        foreach ($this->cssFiles as $css)
        {
            echo '<link href="' . $this->urlToAssets . $css . '" rel="stylesheet">';
        }    
    }
}
```

Then, in ypur controller you can do:

```
$this->load->library('assets');
$this->assets->addCss('cool.css');
$this->assets->addCss('cool.plugin.css');
```

Finally, render the assets in the view:

```
$this->assets->printCssFiles();
```

#### Need to print some javascript files in head section, but also in footer separately?

Then, you can improve the library like:

```
class Assets{

   /** url to assets dir */
   protected $urlToAssets

    /** @var array */
    protected $cssFiles;

    /** @var array */
    protected $jsFiles;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->urlToAssets = base_url('assets/');
        $this->cssFiles = array();
        $this->jsFiles = array();
    }

    function addCss($name)
    {
        $this->cssFiles[] = $name
    }

    function addJs($name, $section = 'header')
    {
        $this->jsFiles[$section] = $name
    }

    function printCssFiles()
    {
        foreach ($this->cssFiles as $css)
        {
            echo '<link href="' . $this->urlToAssets . $css . '" rel="stylesheet">';
        }    
    }

    function printJsFiles($section)
    {
        foreach ($this->jsFiles as $js)
        {
           echo '<script src="' . $this->urlToAssets . $js . '"></script>';
        } 
    }
}
```

Now, in your controller you can do:

```
$this->load->library('assets');
$this->assets->addJs('jquery.js', 'header');
$this->assets->addJs('jquery.plugin.js', 'footer');
```

In the header view you call the respective js files:

```
$this->assets->printJsFiles('header');
```

Or in footer:

```
$this->assets->printJsFiles('footer');
```